# how to assign permission to storage directory in my laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, security, permissions

I created a video player project in laravel. the video will play from only authenticated users.  using the inspect element if anyone gets a video link that is will not download from anyone.

video store location in storage/app/

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` or from OS `sudo chown -R www-data ~yourSite/storage/app`. We need more information.

Comment: @SebastiánPérez as I understand he needs the ability to block video download from the link which is copied from the inspect element

Comment: @sebatiaPerez what information you need to tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage should not be available for clients accessing your server's files. They should only have access to the public folder. What I normally do is creating a route for accessing files in my storage folder. In this route you can check if you want to give access to the file.

Have also a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#downloading-files